# Sum or average of subgradients?, mini-batch SGD keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, gradient

I have searched a lot for how the gradients for a mini-batch in Keras when using the multilayer perceptron are computed, but can't seem to find the answer. I'm wondering if the average of the gradients for each mini-batch is used to update the weights and biases or if it is the sum of the gradients?

Would appreciate if someone could help if they know the answer and if possible tell me where I can find this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to say either average of the loss or sum of the loss, but not average/sum of the gradients.
And I think it's always safe to use average of the loss to calculate the gradients.